# Use an iPad to debug Xamarin.Forms iOS applications

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.forms

I need to develop an iOS application, however I do not have yet an iPhone. I have an iPad Pro, could I use it as debugging device for the iOS app?

Comment: Yes.  Or you can use the iOS simulator

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have Mac device, install XCode, and you could use iphone emulators on Visual Studio on Mac to debug.
2. If you have Mac device and test the code on Windows system, you could connect to your Mac with you Visual Studio on Windows. Check the details about the connection on Ms docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/introduction-to-xamarin-ios-for-visual-studio#connecting-to-the-mac
3. You could connect your iPad to debug you Xamarin.Forms iOS project on Windows before. But for now, there is a bug need to be fixed. You could use the suggestions 1 and 2.

   Bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cant-deploy-to-iOS-Device/10074576?space=8&q=hotrestart&sort=newest

Comment: I have a Mac device, so I can use an iphone emulator on Visual Studio. However, what I need to test are AR functionalities, and for them I need to have a physical device with camera. For this reason I was wondering if there is a way to test on an iPad Pro

Comment: You could use the Mac device to connect to the iPad Pro. It could not connect on Windows.